# How this ElasticSearch query works?

Tags: elasticsearch

I've read Elastic Search documentation but I can not understand how this query works. I just want to know how is the combination of query and filter and another filter.

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": { 
      "query": {
        "match": { "tweet": "full text search" }
      },
      "filter": {
        "range": { "created": { "gte": "now - 1d / d" }}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to explain it to me a bit simpler that this page?
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filtered-query.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one query and one filter:

1. The query part is `{"query": {"match": {"tweet": "full text search" }}}`.
2. The filter part is `{"filter": {"range": {"created": {......}}}}`.

To insert a filter into a query, we have to use **filtered** query DSL.(Note that it is the past participle of "filter".) A filtered query is something like:

```
{"query": {"filtered": {"query": ......}, {"filter": ......} }}
```

Just write any query under the second `"query"` part, any filter under the `"filter"` part.